# How to use between command in 2 string date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using following  select query, but the problem is `IssueDate` column is in `varchar` and it not give correct result. Is any way to use between command string date in SQL:

```
SELECT Pkid AS [Bill Id],
       InvoiceNumber,
       InvoiceType,
       IssueDate,
       FinalTotal
FROM tblInvoiceMain
WHERE IssueDate BETWEEN '01 June 2016' AND '06 June 2016'
ORDER BY Pkid DESC
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Pkid AS [Bill Id],
       InvoiceNumber,
       InvoiceType,
       IssueDate,
       FinalTotal
FROM tblInvoiceMain
WHERE CAST(IssueDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '20160601' AND '20160606'
ORDER BY Pkid DESC
```

If execution time will be very high:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblInvoiceMain
    ADD IssueDate2 AS CAST(IssueDate AS DATE)
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix
    ON dbo.tblInvoiceMain (IssueDate2)
    INCLUDE (Pkid, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceType, IssueDate, FinalTotal)
GO

SELECT Pkid AS [Bill Id],
       InvoiceNumber,
       InvoiceType,
       IssueDate,
       FinalTotal
FROM tblInvoiceMain
WHERE IssueDate2 BETWEEN '20160601' AND '20160606'
ORDER BY Pkid DESC
```

Comment: Error in list of function arguments: 'AS' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: On `SQL Server 2008 R2`: `Command(s) completed successfully.`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with to cast `IssueDate` to a `DATE` type. Also when using date constants, use the `YYYYMMDD` format.

```
SELECT 
    Pkid AS [Bill Id], InvoiceNumber, InvoiceType, IssueDate, FinalTotal 
FROM tblInvoiceMain 
WHERE
    CONVERT(DATE, IssueDate, 106) BETWEEN CAST('20160601' AS DATE) AND CAST('20160606' AS DATE)
ORDER BY Pkid DESC
```

However, if you have an index on `IssueDate`, this will prevent the use of it. My suggestion is to fix your schema and use the proper data type to store your values.

Comment: Are you sure you need to cast the `20160601` as well ?

Comment: @sagi It's not needed, but still it'll be converted to `DATE` behind the scenes in accordance with the [**data type precedence**.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Since `DATE` has a higher data type precedence, '20160601' will be converted to `DATE`.